# R package for implementing firefly algorithm?

Tags: r, optimization

I am interested in implementing firefly algorithm to solve some optimization problems. Since the majority of my work is based on R, I am searching a R package to do it.

Through searching the internet, it is realized that such algorithm is available for "matlab". However, it seems that no package is currently available in R.

Does anyone knows anything or have any suggestion about it?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: I don't know of packages having implemented it but I am confident that you'll probably find an optimization routine for your problem at hand in the CRAN Task View: Optimization and Mathematical Programming ( http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html ). There are some swarm optimizers that follow the same principals as firefly optimization, check them out.

Comment: @user11852, great thanks for your reply. Actually, I have tried some evolutionary approaches, such as genetic algorithm (from package genalg) and particle swarm optimization (from package pso). According to the paper presented by Yang X.S., it seems that firefly algorithm outperforms the other two. Therefore, in my case, I want to do such kind of comparison and that is why the firefly algorithm is desired. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: The link of the paper is attached for reference: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1409.pdf

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("firefly")` finds only packages with data about real (biological) fireflies, so I'm guessing the answer is "no".  Doesn't seem too hard to implement though.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, Thanks for your reply. Could you please offer some clues to implement this algorithm in R? Since I am definitely not an expert in programming, I am wishing that maybe someone could write a basic R code to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Now in R, you can use `metaheuristicOpt` for implementing firefly algorithm.